# virtualbox 4.3.20, centos 6.6 network is unreacheable

Tags: virtualbox

in my network there is a router at address 10.0.0.1 this is closed router, owned by provider of wifi internet, i cant get inside, i cant change anything

my host machine is windows 7 with virtualbox 4.3.20, with static ip address 10.0.0.200, i cant do anything with that it must remain as it is

a try to reach network from guest centos 6.6

i use Host only adapter

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8vl2y03bb7e3l4x/Screenshot%202014-11-27%2012.53.10.png?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fuai2sv8ixr9vlv/Screenshot%202014-11-27%2012.56.04.png?dl=0

i need to ping from guest to ping 8.8.8.8 also ping to host 10.0.0.200 and vice versa, i need to reach network from guest and connect to guest using putty

thanks for help, i tried everythink, but nothing helped

Answer (score 0):

From mcmatak's comment:

> i wasn't able to solve this, even with bridged adapter, but i solved it by new installation based on netinstall (don't know why, but now it works, it seems that the problem is not in virtualbox but in centos configuration)

Comment: finally i wasnt abble to solve this, even with bridged adapter, but i solved it by new installation based on netinstall (dont know why but now it works, seems that the problem is not in virtualbox but in centos configuration)